# GELI / ELI at FreeBSD - changing passphrase

Tags: freebsd, encryption

How can I change/replace the passphrase of an encrypted `eli` provider in FreeBSD? Do I have to recreate the entire provider and copy data, or is there a simpler and faster way?

I've looked in the man pages (which leads me to think there may be some way of doing this through `geli init`) and googled it, but can't find any definite answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`geli setkey`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?geli%288%29). To change from an existing key + phrase to a new key + phrase, you need to specify both the old and the new pair, like so:

```
$ geli setkey -v -k /boot/old.key -K /boot/new.key /dev/md9
Enter passphrase: oldphrase
Enter new passphrase: newphrase
Reenter new passphrase: newphrase
Decrypted Master Key 0.
Note, that the master key encrypted with old keys and/or passphrase may still exists in a metadata backup file.
Done.
```

If your old key had no passphrase, add `-p`, and if you want your new key to be without a passphrase, add `-P`. You do not need to detach first, and you certainly do not need to copy all your data around. Do keep a backup of your metadata for peace of mind, and don't forget to update it after changing keys/passphrases.

**Important:** If you are using boottime passphrase entry (for encrypted root partitions) and are changing from a key + phrase to key without passphrase (`-P` above), you must also disable the boottime passphrase prompt with `geli configure -B`. Furthermore, if you changed keyfile locations, you need to edit `/boot/loader.conf` to point to the new keyfile.

Answer (score 1):

Someone tried it, but failed. Don't remember who but it was some 2 years ago. If you want to be safe, do the copy and re-init.

I just read this on a dead google search result (google ddnt have it cached, but the excerpt still showed):

```
geli detach /dev/md9
```

and then

```
geli setkey ...
```

But i won't guarantee that everything will be fine.

This also seems to be the way for changing from passphrase to keyfiles.

Comment: Hmmmm, I hope there's another answer out there, because that's rather timeconsuming with big volumes. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. Tested, and it works -- at least for me in this test-instance.